# Transcription in powershell works,but the same powershell script doesn't run through cmd prompt

Tags: shell, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have written a powershell script in such a way to get the output on the console as well as into the log file.

I have used the echo commands and the Start/stop transcription

When i execute the script thorough powershell window it works perfect.

The same script when ran through cmd prompt as below doesn't seems to be working

```
    powershell D:\abc.ps1
```

My requirement is to run the powershell using the cmd prompt and get the output on console as well as the log file too.

Any pointers please

Script would be as below:
           abc.ps1 is the powershell

```
       $LogFile="D:\abc_log.log"
       start-transcript -path $LogFile

       Echo "This is log"
       Echo "Hello World"

       stop-transcript
```

When the abc.ps1 is ran through Powershellx86 window it runs and generates the output on window and in log file too.

But when the abc1.ps1 is ran through cmd window as start--> run--> cmd

```
       powershell D:\abc.ps1
```

This doesnt generate the log file with the echos commands in it.But the log is generated with start and stop transcript.

Any idea how to get the echos in the log file too.

Comment: Give sample content of the script.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What happens?

Comment: No error messages,but the transcription works when its ran through powershell window but not when the powershell is ran through the command line as powersell D:\abc.ps1

Comment: @manojds  i have updated the script in the question.Could you please have a look and let me know with your suggestions ?

Comment: Can someone please help me in the above ?

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to not run a powershell script in command prompt. Powershell is your replacement for command prompt, not an extension of it.

Comment: This is not helpful. Sometimes you don't have a choice such as when using Group Policy logon scripts.